Can I programmatically open a new blank text tab from a VSCode extension?
I am developing a new Visual Studio Code extension. It essentially retrieves data from a backend system. I would like to insert the retrieved data into a new blank ("untitled") text editor tab. However, I cannot seem to find a way to do this. I can easily insert the data into a webview panel using vscode.window.createWebviewPanel() function. But it seems for a text editor window (tab) I must first save the retrieved data to a file and then open it using vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(). Is there an API call that I'm missing? This seems like a pretty basic function, but I can't seem to find a way to accomplish it. I am using Visual Studio Code 1.95.1, Node.js 20.18.0 and Windows 11 (Windows_NT x65 10.0.22631). And I am using TypeScript 5.4.4.
Thanks in advance.

vscode.workspace.openTextDocument can also be passed an options object that includes the content to be displayed
 openTextDocument(options?: {content: string, language: string}): Thenable<TextDocument>

Afterwards, you can display it:
const data = await getBackendData();

const document = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument({
  content: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  language: 'plaintext'
});

await vscode.window.showTextDocument(document,  {
  preview: false,
  viewColumn: vscode.ViewColumn.Active
});


Thanks. This worked after one small change.
await vscode.window.showTextDocument(document,  {
Appreciate your help!
